# What method is required to find out "for what values of k is $4x^2+kx+\frac14$ a perfect square?"

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

> For what values of $k$ is this expression a perfect square?
> $$4x^2+kx+\frac14$$

I'm thinking maybe the perfect square trinomial is supposed to be used, as I had to use that formula on the problem prior to this one. However, I don't know how to apply it, since I don't know which of the above terms would be $a^2$, $2ab$ and $b^2$. How can one deduce what term corresponds to what term in the general formula? Or is this not the formula to use at all?

**EDIT:**

User *Exodd* showed a general formula that when I followed, gave the same answer as user *Jitendra Singh*, who answered this question with a different formula.

The general formula is this:

$$(ax+b)^2 = a^2x^2+2abx+b^2$$

Which is a variation on the simpler perfect square trinomial

$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$

Now, if one assumes that $4x^2$ is $a^2x^2$, $kx$ is $2abx$ and $\frac14$ is $b^2$, then the calculation is quite simple. $k$ is then equal to $2ab$, which is equal to $\pm 2$, the sign depending on whether the $4$, or $a^2$, is the product of $2 \times 2$ or $-2 \times -2$, which creates:

$$2 \times 2 \times \frac12 = 2$$

or

$$2 \times -2 \times \frac12 = -2$$

However, this is assuming the aforementioned correspondence. It could be that $4x^2$ is $a^2x^2$, $kx$ is $b^2$ and $\frac14$ is $2abx$. In that case:

$$\frac14 = 2 \times 2 \times \sqrt{kx} \times x$$

or

$$\frac14 = 2 \times -2 \times \sqrt{kx} \times x$$

Furthermore, there could be a different correspondence. What if $4x^2$ is $b^2$, $kx$ is $a^2x^2$ and $\frac14$ is $2abx$? There are other correspondences as well. What says that the first one, that gave the answer of $\pm2$, is correct?

Comment: $(2x+k/4)^2+1/4-(k/4)^2$

Comment: This quadratic in $x$ will be a perfect square iff it has a repeated root.

Comment: or also, you have to equate it to $(ax+b)^2 = a^2x^2 + 2abx + b^2$

Comment: Note that the property of being a perfect square depends on the ambient. It should be a square of what type of object? If we consider continuous real functions it is always a square. Likely you want a square of a polynomial with rational coefficients. You can also consider the problem of it being a square of a polynomial with positive rational coefficients, or many more options are also interesting and produce different answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.math-only-math.com/nature-of-the-roots-of-a-quadratic-equation.html#:%7E:text=Case%20V%3A%20b2%20%2D%204ac,a%20pair%20of%20irrational%20conjugates.) if $b^2=4ac$ then the expression is a perfect square.

So $$ k^2=4 (4) (\frac{1}{4}) $$

So $$ k=±2 $$

Edit:

See I am going to show you why we assume $4k^2$ as $x^2$ and $4$ as $x$.

So lets compare the $2$ expressions-

$$ a^2x^2+2abx+b^2=4x^2+kx+4 $$

Now see if we consider $4x^2$ as $b^2$ then notice this is wrong because $4x^2$ has $x^2$ sign which means $4x^2$ can only considered with a term having $x^2$. Thus we can say-

$$ a^2x^2=4x^2 , 2abx=kx, b^2=4$$

Now you can compare and find the answer like you did in question

Comment: If you don't understand OP then the website says that if $b^2-4ac=0$ then it has equal roots which means if $b^2=4ac$ has equal root and if an expression has equal roots then it is a perfect square. Any more doubts OP?

Comment: Yeah, see the edits I made to my posts. TL;DR, isn't it an assumption to say that kx is 2abx?

Comment: @A.Kvåle I have edited the question Now go through my answer and you will get your comment answer and if still any doubt persist do ask in comments

Answer (score 0):

We consider a *polynomial* in $x$
\begin{align*}
p(x)=4x^2+kx+\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}
which has degree $2$, constant term $\frac{1}{4}$, linear term $kx$ and square term $4x^2$.
We are looking for a representation as perfect square
\begin{align*}
q(x)=(ax+b)^2
\end{align*}

We recall two polynomials are *equal*, i.e. $p=q$ if they have the same degree and the coefficients of like powers of $x$ are equal.
\begin{align*}
p(x)&=q(x)\\
4x^2+kx+\frac{1}{4}&=a^2x^2+2abx+b^2\tag{1}
\end{align*}

From (1) we see $\deg p = \deg q$ and we obtain by comparison of coefficients
\begin{align*}
4&=a^2\\
k&=2ab\\
\frac{1}{4}&=b^2
\end{align*}

*Note:* The equality of polynomials is based upon an *identity theorem* of polynomials which can be found for instance in *[this paper](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emathcircle/circle/2012-13/hw_2013_winter/VietasFormulas.pdf)* as theorem 4 and which is nicely answered by @IvesDaoust in this *[MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463047)*.

Comment: But how do you obtain this correspondence? What method of comparison is being used?

Comment: @A.Kvåle: As stated in the answer we use the definition of equality of polynomials. This means we compare coefficients of equal powers of $x$.